# 1005, "Can't create table 'test.addr_count' (errno: 150)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

/* create table mailing */

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mailing(
                            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            domain VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)ENGINE = InnoDB
```

/* create table addr_count */

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addr_count(
                            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            e_addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            e_domain VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            count INT NOT NULL,
                            INDEX (e_addr),
                            INDEX (e_domain),
                            FOREIGN KEY (e_addr) REFERENCES mailing (addr) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                            FOREIGN KEY (e_domain) REFERENCES mailing (domain) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
                            ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Could you please help me with this error? Everything seems correct to me but not sure what I am missing!

Comment: Both of those columns require an index in the referenced table `mailing`. Instead of creating `INDEX (e_addr), INDEX (e_domain)` in `addr_count` (which is implicit in the `FOREIGN KEY`) create the  two indexes instead on `addr` & `domain` in the `mailing` table.

Comment: Like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe9744